# How to read a file in one coroutine and print lines in another coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to get comfortable with Kotlin/coroutines. My current goal is to read a text file in one coroutine, and emit each line through a Channel to be printed in another coroutine. Here's what I have so far:

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking {

    val ch = Channel<String>()

    launch {
        for (msg in ch) {
            println(msg.length)
        }
    }

    launch {
        File("file.txt").forEachLine {
            ch.send(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this shows my intent, but it doesn't compile because you can't call a suspending function (`send`) from the lambda passed to `forEachLine`. In Golang everything is modeled synchronously, so I would just run it in a goroutine and `send` would block, but Kotlin seems to have a lower level concurrency model. What would be the canonical way to accomplish this?

If it's helpful, my final goal is to read JSON events emitted from a subprocess via stdout. I'll have a separate JSON object on each line, and will need to parse and handle each separately.

Comment: So, why not wrap `ch.send(it)` into `launch { ch.send(it) }`?

Comment: Or use fair `for` loop instead of method accepting lambda: `for (it in File("file.txt").readLines()) { ch.send(it) }`?

Comment: Launch a separate coroutine for every chunk? That seems like a bad idea. I know coroutines are lightweight but that could be a lot of them for no reason. And they're not even guaranteed to run to completion in launch order, right? Conceptually I want it to block until each chunk is sent.

Comment: I don't want to use readLines() because the file could be large and I need to stream it.

Comment: Ok, then you may do `for (line in File("file.txt").bufferedReader().lines()) { ch.send(line) }`

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I've been able to come up with so far. It seems to work but I feel like there must be a more idiomatic way to accomplish this.

```
fun main() = runBlocking {

    val ch = Channel<String>()

    launch {
        for (msg in ch) {
            println(msg.length)
        }
    }

    launch {
        val istream = File("file.txt").inputStream()
        val buf = ByteArray(4096)

        while (true) {
            val n = istream.read(buf)

            if (n == -1) {
                break
            }

            val msg = buf.sliceArray(0..n-1).toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
            ch.send(msg)
        }

        ch.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying the same and based on some ideas I got from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html#fan-out the following seems to work nicely:

```
fun main() {
  val fileToRead = File("somefile.csv")
  runBlocking {
    // Producer reading the file
    val fileChannel = readFileIntoChannel(fileToRead)
    // Consumer writing file lines to stdout
    launch { fileChannel.consumeEach { line -> println(line) } }
  }
}

fun CoroutineScope.readFileIntoChannel(f: File) = produce<String> {
  for (line in f.bufferedReader().lines() ) { send(line) }
}
```